# Multiplying a hexadecimal number by a power of 16

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation

This question is adapted from Patterson and Hennessy (5th Ed). Given that `$t0 = 0xaaaaaaaa`, what is `$t1` in `sll $t1, $t0, 44`?

My approach is to convert `$t0 << 44` into `$t0 * 2^44 = $t0 * 16^11`. How do I proceed from here? Wouldn't the `<< 44` cause an overflow?

Edit: I believe that the question has a typo as pointed out by Ped7g. It should be `$t0 << 4` or `sll $t1, $t0, 4`.

Comment: you're right. each 'multiplying by 16' is equivalent to 'shift left 4 bits'. In a 32bit register, the result will be 0. in 64 bit, you will have $aaaaa followed by 11 0's

Comment: Maybe it's a typo and it was supposed to demonstrate multiplying by 16, i.e. shift left by 4?

Comment: Yes, I believe it has a typo. If not, the answer would be 0x0.

Comment: @Tommylee2k: 32-bit MIPS `sll` only has a 5-bit field for immediate shift counts, so a left-shift by 44 that zeros a whole register is not encodeable.  (http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).  Only shift-counts of 0..31 are encodeable, so `sll $t1, $t0, 44` should generate an assembler warning or error.  If only a warning, the result might be that your assembler puts the low 5 bits of `44` into the instruction, i.e. shift count = `44&31 = 12`.  (This is for classic MIPS; I didn't look at the most recent MIPS32r6 manual to see if the encoding changed, or the 64-bit ver.)

Comment: @PeterCordes  true. With only 32 bit registers, more wouldn't make sense anyways. I Didn't knew it was MIPS, since the OP didn't tell us, and I don't know MIPS, so I didn't recognize it from the instruction; So my comment wasn't focused on MIPS anyways, but more generally speaking

Comment: @Tommylee2k: it's common in general for instruction sets to mask shift counts, or (if it's a bitfield inside an instruction word, unlike x86) to not provide enough count bits to shift out all the register bits.  But yeah, this looks like MIPS, and I think Patterson and Hennessy use some MIPS examples.  OP definitely should have tagged MIPS if it really is MIPS.